# Rvest: why does the following xpath returns empty list

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to extract the titles using `rvest` from rotten tomatoes

I use the following codes:

```
urlhtml<-read_html("http://www.rottentomatoes.com/browse/opening/")
df<-html_text(html_nodes(urlhtml,xpath="//*[@id='movies-collection']/div/div/div[2]/a"))
```

the `xpath` is derived from google chrome so I believe it's correct, however, it returns empty list... I can't figure out what is wrong.

Could anyone help?
Much appreciated

Comment: Are you sure the elements are there in the document you fetch or could they be dynamically added later by javascript?

Comment: I am not an expert in web programming but i did see the elements in the html inspect so i believe they dont use javascript

Comment: @RogerLindsjö, is there anyway I can check the case if it's dynamically added by javascript? And if that is the case, what can I do to scrape the data? Could you share your knowledge please?

Comment: Don't know R, but could you output the html you fetch? Getting the content using wget or curl indicates that there is no movie information in the html. You could try to find a component that would run the JavaScript to fetch the rest of the content, but a better solution would be to use http://developer.rottentomatoes.com

Comment: Use [omdbapi](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/omdbapi). It's less cumbersome than the RT API. And, scraping RT is a violation of their Terms of Service.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, it turns out like @RogerLindsjö said, I need a javascript to parse the html first and use phantomjs to cooperate R scrapping