# Scrape football elo-ratings with rvest

Tags: r, xpath, rvest

I am trying to harvest the [world football elo ratings](http://www.eloratings.net/2014_World_Cup_start) with `rvest` but I keep getting an empty list

Using the *inspect element* in *google chrome* I get the xpath `//*[(@id = "maintable_2014_World_Cup_start")]/div[6]`

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

page<-"http://www.eloratings.net/2014_World_Cup_start"

elo_rating<-read_html(page)%>%
   html_nodes(xpath='//[@id="maintable_World"]/div[6]')%>%
   html_table()
```

I get an empty list

Searching online and within SE, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36639127/rvest-why-does-the-following-xpath-returns-empty-list) and perhaps it has to do something with javascript (which I know nothing about..:). Also, when at the page source (with google chrome) I see a lot of calls to javascript

Lastly, I came across [this](https://rpubs.com/RobWHickman/SoccerAesthetics1markdown) R publication, with an example of extracting data from the same website, but when I try to replicate the R code, I still get empty lists and empty character objects

I went through many threads here in SE ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633708/rvest-html-nodes-span-div-and-xpath/48633772#48633772), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49336132/empty-nodes-when-scraping-links-with-rvest-in-r), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35707534/how-to-scrape-a-table-with-rvest-and-xpath?rq=1) but I can't find a solution

If the obstacle is javascript, is there anything I can do to extract the data?

Answer (score 1):

The obstacle does seem to be javascript as the tables are generated by it. I think you need to use PhantomJS to render the tables and grab them. [See this page for help.](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scraping-javascript-generated-data-with-r)

Comment: Many thanks for the tip! Greatly appreciate it! Will check it out and let you know how it went